# ML - compiling to object file only (no link)

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm trying with the following argument:

```
ml.exe "c:\src\dllmain.asm" /c /Fo"c:\src\dllmain.obj"
```

Output is:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: C:\src\dllmain.asm
```

It seems to have worked, but the object file is no where to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.
"any corresponding /Fo options must be specified before /c."